# Creating a specific matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to create the following matrix

```
A <- matrix(0,n,n)
for(i in 1:n){
  for(j in 1:n){
    if(abs(i - j) == 1) A1[i,j] <- 1
  }
}
```

Is there another way to create such a matrix? I just want to avoid using for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple option is using `outer` + `abs`

```
> +(abs(outer(1:n,1:n,`-`))==1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

where `n <- 7`

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a matrix with 0 values
2. Subtract row index with column index.
3. Replace values in matrix with 1 where the difference is 1 or -1

```
n <- 5
A <- matrix(0,n,n)
inds <- row(A) - col(A)
A[abs(inds) == 1] <- 1
A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    1
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

where `row(A) - col(A)` (`inds`) returns :

```
inds
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4
#[2,]    1    0   -1   -2   -3
#[3,]    2    1    0   -1   -2
#[4,]    3    2    1    0   -1
#[5,]    4    3    2    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of code by using the function `stats::toeplitz`, which follows the idea in the answer by Ronak Shah.

```
f1 <- function(n)
{
  A <- matrix(0,n,n)
  inds <- row(A) - col(A)
  A[abs(inds) == 1] <- 1
  A
}

n <- 10
A1 <- f1(n)
A2 <- toeplitz(c(0,1,rep(0,n-2)))
all.equal(A1, A2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` - `crossing` to get the combinations of sequence, then
get the `abs`olute difference (`-`) between the columns, check if it is equal to 1, and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(n1 = 1:n, n2 = 1:n) %>% 
    mutate(new = +(abs((n1 - n2)) == 1)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = n2, values_from = new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#     n1   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     0     1     0     0     0
#2     2     1     0     1     0     0
#3     3     0     1     0     1     0
#4     4     0     0     1     0     1
#5     5     0     0     0     1     0
```

---

Or another option with `diag` from `base R`

```
+(abs(row(diag(n)) - col(diag(n))) == 1)
```

-output

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    1
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0
```